# How to float div sections within another div in a form?

Tags: html, css, forms, css-float

My goal is to have the checkbox to the left of the image, and have the info corresponding to the picture on the right, but that isn't happening. This is all part of a form, if that makes a difference. Do you have any suggestions? 
this is my html:

```
      <div id="bookz">
      <input type="checkbox" name="book1">
      <div id="b11">
        <img src="tewwg.jpg" alt="Their Eyes Were Watching God book cover" height=280 id="bimg1"><br>
        <div id="b1">
      Their Eyes Were Watching God by Zora Neale Hurston <br>
      Price: 12.85 <br>
      Quantity: <input id="bqua1" type="text" size="5"><br>
    </div>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="book2">
    <div id="b22">
      <img src="beloved.jpg" alt="Beloved Book Cover" height=280 id="bimg2">
      <div id="b2">
      Beloved by Toni Morrison<br>
      Price: 15.75<br>
      Quantity: <input id="bqua2" type="text" size="5"><br>
    </div>
    </div>
```

& this is my css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
body{
  background: #ffbae1;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ff9c42, #ffc3b7);
}
img{
  border-style: dotted;
}
h1, h2, form, button, #tot, #gtot, #shipping{
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
  text-align: center;
}
#b1, #b2{
  float: right;
  margin: 2px;
}
#tot{
  margin-top: 5px;
  align: center;
}
#info, #bookz{
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve], also see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

When floating divs you need a width and a display. So you can achieve this by adding a certain `width` for your floated div and `display: inline-block` for your divs.

In the example that you have given, I added the following styles:

```
#b1,#b2{
  float: right;
  width:80%;
  height:auto;
  margin: 2px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display:inline-block;
}

#b11,#b22{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

By adding that to your styles I did achieve this:

[image]

I assume that this is what you want to do? But correct me if I am wrong.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaq1b6k9/).